# Java Mock final void method using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I needed some help in understanding how to Unit test the below. I have the following classes structure. I have to follow the structure as is, since this is as per our product's framework, and I can not deviate from this.

```
package com.rohan.base

import javax.inject.Inject;

public abstract class ServiceBase {

    @Inject
    protected CommandExecutorBase commandExecutor;

    public final void execute() {
        commandExecutor.execute(this);
    }   
}

--------------------------------------------------------

package com.rohan.services

public class MyService extends ServiceBase {
    public void someMethod() {} 
}

--------------------------------------------------------

package com.rohan.delegates

import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.rohan.services.MyService

public class MyDelegate {

    @Inject
    MyService myService;

    public void callService() {
        myService.execute();
    }   
}
```

I am trying to do a TDD approach for the coding, and I want to ensure that the `callService` method in the delegate class, calls the `execute` method on the Service class.

I tried the following approach, but it gives me a Null Pointer exception in the execute method (because the `commandExecutor` object is null). 
Can someone please advise me how can I do this?
I am not allowed to use PowerMockito.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyDelegateUnitTests {

    @Test
    public void validateServiceExecuteIsCalled() {
        MyDelegate delegate = new MyDelegate();
        MyService serviceObject = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
        delegate.myService = serviceObject;
        Mockito.doAnswer((i) -> {
            System.out.println("I am here");
            return null;
        }).when(serviceObject).execute();
        Mockito.verify(serviceObject, Mockito.times(1)).execute();
    }   
}
```

I can not mock the commandExecutor object, as it is not accessible (different package from my Delegate class).
In place of `Mockito.doAnswer()`, I also tried `Mockito.doNothing().when(serviceObject).execute();`
But I get the same exception. Can someone please advise me, when I am trying to define a mock in the `when` methods, why does it go ahead and try to execute the real method?
Thanks!

**Update**
I modified the test class, and added the folder/file mockito-extensions (as suggested by @jokster in the answers below). However, I end up with the below exception. I am using Mockito 2.

My Test Class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyDelegateUnitTests {

    MyDelegate delegate;
    MyService serviceObject;

    @Before
    public void setUpMocks() {
        delegate = new MyDelegate();
        serviceObject = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(serviceObject).execute();
        delegate.myService = serviceObject;     
    }

    @Test
    public void validateSettersAreCalled() {
        delegate.callService();
        Mockito.verify(serviceObject, Mockito.times(1)).execute();
    }
}
```

I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
        at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
        at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
        at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
        at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:30)
        at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:12)
        at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:11)
        at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
        at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:44)
        at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:975)
        at com.rohan.delegates.MyDelegateUnitTests.setUpMocks(MyDelegateUnitTests.java:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final , you have to activate mocking final methods: Simply create a file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/mock-marker-inline`.

Then final methods should work just like any others.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above approach, but ended up in an exception. Have updated my question with the details. Can you please have a look and advise? thanks!

Comment: @RohanBhattacharya sorry. Haven't tried it myself. Was only a quick google research.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your unit test, I don't see a need for defining the behavior of `myService.execute` method. Defining the behavior is kind of unnecessary

```
 Mockito.doAnswer((i) -> {
        System.out.println("I am here");
        return null;
    }).when(serviceObject).execute();
```

You can remove the above code.

It is enough to verify that the `execute` method is been called with the right number of times. To answer your question, one suggestion would be to do with constructor based injection. Basically create a constructor for `MyDelegate` and inject `Myservice`. And in the test, do the following:

```
MyService serviceObject = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);      
MyDelegate delegate = new MyDelegate(serviceObject);
```

Other option would be to use `@InjectMocks` and `@Inject` in the tests if you dont want to have constructor based injection in your delegate class.

Comment: Thanks @Thiru. But this is eventually the same thing that I was doing. I needed suggestions on how to handle the above case, where I have a final void method, with a variable which I cannot access from my test class. Also, I cannot have a constructor with parameters, as this will break the existing framework which I have to comply to. Thanks!