# Mockito error "Only void methods can doNothing()" while trying to mock a void method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im experimenting with Mockito and am encountering an error while trying to mock a void method: "Only void methods can doNothing()!".  However the method Im trying to mock is a void method:
`void com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setStructured(int n, String tvpName, SQLServerDataTable tvpDataTable) throws SQLServerException`

Here's what Im doing

```
public class MockitoTest {
    @Mock private Connection mockConnection;
    @Mock private SQLServerPreparedStatement mockStatement; 


    @Test
    public void mockitoTest() throws SQLException
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(mockConnection.prepareStatement(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockStatement);
        
        // Can mock this and it doesnt give me any errors
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockStatement).addBatch(Mockito.isA(String.class));

        // This throws me the mentioned MockitoException, even through setStructured is void
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockStatement).setStructured(1, Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(SQLServerDataTable.class));

        // ... 
    }
```

As per my comment, I can mock SQLServerPreparedStatement's addBatch method, but not the setStructured method?  Both are void methods.  Why does Mockito think setStructured is not a void method?

Im using this versions:

```
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
```

Comment: Could you print implementation of addBatch and setStructured inside to SQLServerPreparedStatement class to understand if everything is correct?

Comment: The methods are final. Don't know if Mockito can instrument that. https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerPreparedStatement.java

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Gimby for pointing out the issue.  It was in fact related to the method being final.

A few references that helped me out:

- [Java Mock final void method using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418475/java-mock-final-void-method-using-mockito)
- https://www.davidvlijmincx.com/posts/writing_higher_quality_tests_with_mockitos_inline_mock_maker/

Comment: Indeed. You can ask a followup question about that: then why did it complain about setStructured() even though addBatch() is instrumented first and it is final too? Mockito works in mysterious ways.